# Influence of employee stats on game quality

Tags: game-dev-story

Each employee has three stats

- Program
- Scenario
- Graphics
- Sound

a current job (with level 1-5) and any number of previous jobs in the work history.

How do these stats influence the quality of the game and the employee effectiveness when they're writing the proposal, designing the graphics or composing the sound?

Is only the current job title important, or does also the work history play a role? What are the advantages of producers and directors?

Answer (score 2):

Each stat has its usage in the game, like Scenario for writing game proposal, Graphics for game design and Sound for creating music for the game. An employee with higher points for Scenario, for example, would be a better choice to create a game proposal. More scenario points, combined with the level of the employee, means more points for Fun and Creativity. Similarly, a person with higher points for Sound, would be a better choice for creating music.

If you hire an employee that has some levels already achieved in multiple categories, you have the option of choosing a different employee each time for any particular activity (Game proposal, Graphics, Sound). If I am going to hire a guy I will prefer an employee who is currently a designer level 2, and has been a sound engineer level 3, and coder level 3 (just an example), than a guy who is simply a designer level 2. Obviously, I would have to pay the person more. Work history was particularly useful for me in the game as I switched an employee's job and then raised up his level to 5 for each job, to make him a hardware engineer, and eventually a hacker (Though now I know that this is the longer and more expensive route. If you want a hacker, just hire one. :) ).

Hiring Producers and Directors helps for the same reason, that you can use him/her as a writer, designer, sound engineer.

Answer (score 1):

The current job title is important. Writers will do a better job of making proposals than Artists, Artists will do a better job of designing characters than Coders, etc. That assumes equality of stats. I believe the stats affect performance in their corresponding tasks: scenario affects proposals, graphics affects design, sound affects music. The Coding stat I believe relates to your workers performance while the game is being produced, and relates to their abilities for bursts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if work history plays in role in game quality, but once each of their jobs reaches the top level you will be able to develop your own console.